# Throttling events - Perfomance implications of adding and removing event listeners

Tags: javascript

This isn't a problem I'm having - it's more just a general interest query.

I've just implemented throttling on scroll events on my web app. I've done it in the way all tutorials teach you i.e. inside your function, you block the rest of its execution using some timer controlled variable which makes you wait until the function can be run again.

My question is this: surely in this case, on every scroll event, the function *is* still being run, it's just that the function is quickly exited so it doesn't take much of a performance hit.

I'm surprised that the standard correct way to throttle events isn't something like:

- Add an event listener that runs a function.
- When event occurs, run the function, remove the event listener and then set up a timeout to re-add the event listener at a later time.

I presume people far cleverer than me have thought of this and there are good reasons why not to do this.

Is it because it's unnecessarily fiddly? Is it much more processor intensive to add and remove listeners than it is to run empty functions?

I'm just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those is a performance concern. Starting to run a function and then bailing out is very cheap, and so too is adding/removing event listeners. So if you have a situation that can be solved by adding and removing event listeners, and it's easier to under than the other options, feel free to do it.

I can think of a couple reasons why i wouldn't do it though

1. It's narrow. There are very few problems that can be solved by removing an event listener. Throttling, yes, but even a very similar feature -- debouncing -- can't be done by removing the event listener. (Debouncing means to wait until there's a period of inactivity. So if the function keeps getting called quickly, you'll keep delaying longer. If you remove the event listener, you lose the ability to know that you need to wait longer)
2. You have to know how to tear down and set up the event listener. For your case that may be fine, but a general-purpose throttle utility (Eg, [lodash's throttle function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle)) may have no idea how the function is going to be called. If you use the setTimeout approach instead, then it will work regardless of how it's being called.